# a supporting effort along the axes

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The Russian attack on Kyiv likely consists of a main effort aimed at enveloping and ultimately encircling the city from the west and a supporting ***effort along*** the axes from Chernihiv and Sumy to encircle Kyiv from the east.

[Reference](https://www.understandingwar.org/backgrounder/russian-offensive-campaign-assessment-march-1)

---

I'm not sure if "***effort***" means "a serious attempt" or "a piece of hard work" and if "***along***" means "from one end towards the other end of something".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's "**supporting effort**" and it means "an effort to support." "**Along the axes**" means each axis will have this "supporting effort."

"**Axes**" is just plural for "axis."

"**effort**" alone means: "a vigorous or determined attempt" according to oxford languages. And, in this case they are talking about a "war effort" since they are at war. A definition from Wikipedia is "In politics and military planning, a war effort is a coordinated mobilization of society's resources—both industrial and human —towards the support of a military force."

The entire sentence could instead be phrased like so:

> The Russian attack on Kyiv likely consists of a main effort aimed at enveloping and ultimately encircling the city from the west along with a supporting effort from Chernihiv and Sumy to encircle Kyiv from the east.

"**Axes**" is not necessary; it just emphasizes the direct path from one city to the next, but that can be inferred.

Comment: I'd also like to know what "***effort***" means in that context.

Comment: @Aaaaaaassssss I updated my answer with further explanation.